# REST API over WCF has stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest, routes

I have server that works with MVC web site and exposed REST API on same web.config file.

Everything was fine but suddenly rest API start to return:

> The resource cannot be found

I search deeply this issue and didn't find any changes on the code that may cause this issue. Other server with the same code version works fine.

I used RouteDebug tool and got output that the rougting for the rest API is broken.
What can cause it and How can I fix it?

The routing is on the global.asax.cs file as the follow:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyServices", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyServicesType)));
```

Web.config:

```
<service name="namespace.MyServices">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="namespace.IMyServices" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Thanks a lot,
N.

Comment: Are you registering your WebApiConfig on App start before RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes? If not, can you try to swap them and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.
My Calls in Global.asax.cs are like that:
"AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);"
I can't see where the config file is registered but I think it's the IIS service doing it before the application code actually started.

Answer (score 0):

After tough days I find weird soluton to this issue.

I removed from my web.config file the services description and it's started to work.
Still not sure why it's work but it stable now.

Thanks,
Naftali.